# Backward compatibility problem with boost serialization 1:73

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

we are using boost serialization for writing and reading data and just switched from boost 1:67 to boost 1:73.
We now cannot read back the data written with boost 1:67 or prior. We get an archive_exception::input_stream_error exception.

Examining the files shows the difference. The old files are starting with

22 serialization::archive 16

The new files are missing this data. Removing it from the files enabled the reading with boost 1:73.

But strangely, if trying a small example program (the gps example from the documentation) also boost 1:73 produces this data:
22 serialization::archive 18

Any idea what has changed in between these versions and could cause this problem? Thanks in advance for any hint.

Our application uses an own derived archive class. Maybe I have to changed something there?

Best regards

Kai Benndorf

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround myself.

Our own archive was derived from e.g. boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl.
If I add the following code to its constructor it works again:

```
if(0 == (flags & boost::archive::archive_flags::no_header))
     init();
```

I found this code in the text_iarchive class, which is derived from text_iarchive_impl, what looks strange to me.

Is this a bug or should I use another class to derive our own archives from?

Comment: That's not a workaround. That's actually correct behaviour. So it was a bug